# jQuery UI slide doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, user-interface, slide

I have a jQuery script for sliding an element page to left when the link is clicked. It works for every famous browser except IE. How can I fix this?

Here is the script:

```
$("a.openHome").click(function(){
    $(".halamanContact").hide('slide', {direction: 'left'},'slow');
});
```

Comment: D'you get an error in the console (F12) ?

Comment: what do you mean?  @didier ghys

Comment: do you mean from dreamweaver? @Didier Ghys

Comment: Well this piece of code is very simple so it's weird it does not work in IE specifically. Maybe there is a javascript error. You can check that by opening the IE Developer Tools (press F12 in the browser) and checking the console tab.

Comment: you really think that code working properly on IE? then maybe my IE browser error @DidierGhys

Comment: i use IE 8, what you think? it should be work? @DidierGhys

Comment: This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/6weaw/) with your code works in IE 7 to 9 for me.

Comment: then my IE8 browser got error.. thanks man @DidierGhys how to give +1 in this?

Comment: You can't because there is no answer, but it's ok, i did not really solved your problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and in my case it was related to jQuery UI 1.8 script calling a method on the object `console`.
Removing the string `this.debug&&console.log.apply("",arguments)` from the file fixed my problem.

Comment: That code shouldn't even execute unless you've set the debug flag. And the only place I can find `this.debug` in the jQuery UI library is in datePicker, not effects.